How does electronic configuration change for chromium anions?
In my textbook introducing orbitals, I am told:

The $\mathrm{4s}$ subshell has a lower energy level than the $\mathrm{3d}$ subshell, thus, the $\mathrm{4s}$ subshell fills up first.

But I am also given the following exception:

Chromium and Copper are badly behaved. They donate one of their $\mathrm{4s}$ electrons to the $\mathrm{3d}$ subshell because they're more stable with a full or half full shell.

I understand this so far, but then I started thinking about Chromium (& Copper) ions/anions, and wondered: what would their electronic configurations be?
Whilst researching, I found the following resources:

Chemistry Stack Exchange: What is the electronic configuration of Cr (+1) ion?
How to Write the Electron Configuration for Chromium (Cr, Cr2+, and Cr3+)

These two sources have shown me that for ions $\mathrm{Cr}^{+}$, $\mathrm{Cr}^{2+}$ & $\mathrm{Cr}^{3+}$, we would 'prioritise' the $\mathrm{3d}$ subshell, and first remove electrons from the $\mathrm{4s}$ subshell.
But what about anions?
Say we had the anions $\mathrm{Cr}^{-}$, $\mathrm{Cr}^{2-}$ & $\mathrm{Cr}^{3-}$, what would their electronic configurations be?
Thanks!

I'm also going to assume any answers given can be applied likewise to Copper ions.

There are no $\ce{Cr^2- nor Cr^3-}$ ions.

Wait really? Sorry I'm quite new to chemistry but, they just don't exist?! Good to know!

What about $\mathrm{Cr}^{-}$?

$\ce{Cr^-}$ exists. Here is a list of anions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_affinity_(data_page)#Elements

As others have pointed out, atomic metal anions (or indeed, metals in negative oxidation states) are pretty rare in stable compounds, and I believe only a handful of 1- oxidation state metal compounds have been found to exist and no 2- or greater charged metal compounds, but I don't have a source for that besides an inorganic chemistry lecture course I took some time ago. This however, does not preclude the possibility of gas-phase metal anions like Cr-, or even higher charged anions (I'm getting a web server error for the journals tonight trying to link particular articles, but a quick search shows several examples). These are able to exist long enough to be studied because the atoms are essentially isolated. So, even though an atomic Cr anion may not come into play in typical chemistry, the question is certainly of theoretical interest and may even be something experimentally accessible.
I don't have a definitive answer for you in terms of what electron configuration you would expect Cr- to have, but I can certainly point you in the direction of the factors at play. This is unfortunately a case where you have two different competing effects, so I am not sure a definitive answer exists without doing calculations, although I may be wrong about that.
The reason why the half-filled d subshell is favored to begin with has to do with exchange energy. Exchange energy is a complex phenomenon, and a deep understanding of it requires quantum physics, but essentially - since electrons are all identical, the quantum mechanical system of the atom cannot distinguish between two electrons in the same subshell (that is, 3p, 4d, 4s, 4p, etc.) that also have the same spin. You can read a little more about exchange interactions from a physics perspective in this post. Personally, I think about it as since the electrons are indistinguishable, they all kind of "spread out" across the space they can all occupy and become a little "further apart." Someone with more QM background may be able to point you to a better intuition for this.
Regardless of the deeper idea behind it, the exchange interaction exists, and it means that electrons with the same spin in the same subshell are somewhat stabilized. Most of the time this is not enough stabilization to make a difference in electron configuration. For example, 2p orbitals do not borrow electrons from the 2s. This is because the fundamental energy difference between those orbitals due to proximity to the nucleus is so large that exchange energy can never bring them close. In the case of d electrons though, the 4s and 3d orbitals are close enough in energy that the stabilization from having 5 electrons that can all participate in exchange interactions puts the 4s1 3d5 configuration slightly lower energy than 4s2 3d4.
Putting in an extra electron gets complicated, though. In favor of adding the electron to the 4s orbital is that orbital having a lower overall energy, and not breaking up the favorable 3d5 exchange interactions. On the other hand, the energy cost of pairing two electrons in the same orbital (due to repulsion) does depend on the orbital in question, and I am not sure how 4s and 3d would compare in this regard. I suspect that the [Ar] 4s2 3d5 configuration would be lower energy for Cr-, but that is pure speculation on my part.

"...between two electrons in the same subshell (that is, 3p, 4d, 4s, 4p, etc.)"
Did you mean 4s, 4d, 4p & 4f? Sorry if this seems like a dumb question but I am quite new to this idea and I just wanted to check whether it's a typo or if I haven't learnt something properly.

Not a typo! So, a "shell" means the set of orbitals with the same principal quantum number - that is, 4s, 4d, 4p (4f doesn't exist for complex QM math reasons, but if it did, yes, same shell.) "Subshell" means the set of orbitals with the same principal quantum number and "angular momentum quantum number" (that is, the same type of orbital, s, p, d, f). So when I say "the same subshell" I mean electrons that are both in 4s, or 3d, or 2p, or some other combination of number and s, p, d, f orbitals. Hopefully that makes sense.

The system of the atom can distinguish between electrons in the same shell but different subshells, like for example, between a spin up electron in 3s and a spin up electron in 3p. This is because those orbitals have different shapes and thus different energies.
